# Thymeleaf скрыть popup по-умолчанию

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

При открытии основной страницы, по-умолчанию, блок `<div id="er">` виден в виде пустого прямоугольника. Есть ли возможность его сделать невидимым при открытии основной страницы. Что бы блок `<div id="er">` был виден только при передачи наличии данных в `${error}`.

```
<body>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="/main">Добавить </a><a href="/search">Поиск</a>
</div>
</br>
<div id="er">
    <div id="popup">
    <strong style="color: rgb(20, 85, 162);" th:each="err : ${error}" th:text="${err}"></strong>
    <p style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('er').style.display='none';" >Закрыть</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

и CSS

```
#er {
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
 
#popup {
  background-color: #00f;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40%;
  color: #f00;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: <body>
<div class="menu"> - он в каком файле? html или php или у вас шаблонизатор используется?

Comment: Файл .html. Шаблонизатор thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы можете это сделать на серверной части или на клиентской - например на js
прописав функцию

```
<div id="er" onload="var a = '${error}'; if(a){this.disabled = true;}">
```

или на сервере

```
<div id="er" <?php if($error){ echo 'disabled' }?> >
</div>
```

а если у вас шаблонизатор - так пользуйтесь его конструкциями и пишите в заголовке к вопросу именно название шаблонизатора

```
<div id="er" th:if="${error}">
</div>
```